# Creating Edittext dynamically from API response

Tags: java, android, json, api

I am creating edit text dynamically from API response in Linear layout at for loop & setting the hint from api response. Now what I want is that for two Fields I want single `edittext` should be created instead of individual for both of them. I need to put a condition for linear layout that if one edit text with so n so hint already exists then come out of loop & not create/add edit text.

Any ideas. here is my code.

for **type=1** I want  2 edit text should be created 1 for either Smart Card/ Customer Relation and other for Amount.

```
 API Response

     "listValidators": [
            {
                "inputType": 1,
                "lableName": "Smart Card Number",
                "message": "Smart Card Number starts with 4 or 1 and have only 11 digits",
                "productId": 1218,
                "regex": "^[4|1]{1}[0-9]{10}$"
            },
            {
                "inputType": 1,
                "lableName": "Amount",
                "message": "Amount must be between Rs.10 and Rs.10000",
                "productId": 1218,
                "regex": "^([0-9]{2,4})$|^10000$"
            },
            {
                "inputType": 1,
                "lableName": "Customer Relation Number",
                "message": "Customer Relation Number starts with 4 or 1 and have only 11 digits",
                "productId": 1218,
                "regex": "^[4|1]{1}[0-9]{10}$"
            },
            {
                "inputType": 10,
                "lableName": "Recharge Now",
                "message": "",
                "productId": 1218,
                "regex": ""
            }
        ]

    Java Code

    for(final Validators v : validators){
                    if(v.type == 1){ //inputType
                        // 1 editable text


                        if(vendorId==220){
                            EditText tv = new EditText(this);
                            //tv.setId(viewOffest++);

                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            tvLayoutParams.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
                            tv.setLayoutParams(tvLayoutParams);

                            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dynamic_text_size_medium));
                            //tv.setHint("Enter " + v.text);
                            tv.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.parent_filled);
                            tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                            if(v.regex.contains("a-z"))
                                tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                            d(LS, "adding inputype "+ v.type + " to view");
                            tv.setTag(R.string.tag_hint_validator, validators);
                            tv.setOnFocusChangeListener(hintListener);

    //flexisection is Linear layout here is confusion

                            if(flexiSection.getTag.equals("Smart Card Number")  
     ||flexiSection.getTag().equals("Customer Relation Number")){ 
                                break;
                            }
                            flexiSection.addView(tv);


                        }

                        else{

                            EditText tv = new EditText(this);
                            //tv.setId(viewOffest++);

                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            tvLayoutParams.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
                            tv.setLayoutParams(tvLayoutParams);

                            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dynamic_text_size_medium));
                            tv.setHint("Enter " + v.text);
                            tv.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.parent_filled);
                            tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                            if(v.regex.contains("a-z"))
                                tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                            d(LS, "adding inputype "+ v.type + " to view");
                            flexiSection.addView(tv);
                            tv.setTag(R.string.tag_hint_validator, validators);
                            tv.setOnFocusChangeListener(hintListener);
                        }

    Any responses will be appreciated.
```

Comment: Better to go with **[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)**

Comment: I did not done coding for this, its already there. I just want to edit minimal things possible.

Comment: Please check the code. its creating three edit text. i want either of them for Smartcard and Customer Relation

Comment: smartcard and customer Relation is just string response from api, not any android terms. in short just need to create single edit text from 2  string field responses.

Comment: I didnt got your point. new Edittext means. need to break the for loop if either of one edit text already exists.

Comment: is there any other medium where we can talk. I really appreciate your reply and need help ?

Comment: ya actually need to create ui through java. can you help me resolve this. i dont thing its a big deal for experienced developer

Comment: because I need to change coding for whole project then and i just started working in android it will be troublesome situation for me.  right now I am getting 3 edittext in output. I need to put condition for linear layout that if it contains one view with hint "Smarccard/cust" if yes then come out of loop and not create edittext. thats it ?

Comment: Check This Out  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411703/7642429

Comment: I need to create 2 edittext i tried this as above post. but didn't worked for me. 
 for(int i=0;i<1;i++){flexiSection.addView(tv);}